# Separating MXML and Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

From this tutorial http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/11010.aspx
I found the code below.  Is there a way to break this out so the mxml file just has the mxml, and the code between the script tags is put in an actionscript file?

Thanks.

-Nick

```
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute"
    width="600"
    height="400"
    frameRate="100"
    creationComplete="CreationComplete()"
    enterFrame="EnterFrame(event)">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
        public function CreationComplete():void
        {

        }

        public function EnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {

        }
    ]]></mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this in Flex:

- Put the AS code in a .as file and use the "source=yourfile.as" [attribute in the Script tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_4.html):

`<mx:Script source="yourfile.as" />`

You can also use the `includes="yourfile.as"` declaration w/in the Script tag:

```
<mx:Script
    <![CDATA[
        include "yourfile.as";

        //Other functions
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

---

- Use a [Code-Behind](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Code+Behind) pattern where you define the code in an AS file which extends the visual component you want your MXML file to extend.  Then your MXML file simple extends the AS file and you have (via inheritance) access to all the code.  It would look something like this (I'm not sure if this would work for the main MXML file which extends `Application`):

AS File:

```
package {
    public class MainAppClass {
        //Your imports here
        public function CreationComplete():void {
        }
        public function EnterFrame(event:Event):void {
        }
    }
}
```

MXML File:

```
<component:MainAppClass xmlns:component="your namespace here"
                        xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                        layout="absolute"
                        width="600"
                        height="400"
                        frameRate="100"
                        creationComplete="CreationComplete()"
                        enterFrame="EnterFrame(event)">
</component:MainAppClass>
```

---

- Use a framework to inject the functionality you are looking for as a type of "model" which contains the data-functionality you will use.  It would look *something* like this in Parsley:

  ```
      <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
              layout="absolute"
              width="600"
              height="400"
              frameRate="100"
              creationComplete="model.CreationComplete()"
              enterFrame="model.EnterFrame(event)">

              <mx:Script>
                  <![CDATA[
                      [Inject]
                      [Bindable]
                      public var model:YourModelClass;
                  ]]>
             </mx:Script>
     </mx:Application>
  ```

Two frameworks which come to mind which can help w/injection are [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/) or [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/).

---

I'm not sure if the code-behind pattern works with the main MXML file (which extends Application), so if you're having problems, you might try breaking out the content in your Main MXML file into a separate component which is included in Main.  It might look something like this:

Main.mxml:

```
<mx:Application blah,blah,blah>
    <component:YourComponent />
</mx:Application>
```

YourComponent.mxml:

```
<component:YourComponentCodeBehind creationComplete="model.creationComplete()"...>
  //Whatever MXML content you would have put in the Main file, put in here
</component:YourComponentCodeBehind>
```

YourComponentCodeBehind.as

```
package {
    class YourComponentCodeBehind {
        //Whatever AS content you would have put in the Main .as file, put in here
    }
}
```

From what I've been able to gather from Flex architecture, this is a very common way of setting up your application: your main MXML includes a single "view" which is the entry-point to the rest of your application.  This view the contains all other views which comprise the app.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I'd like to go with the code behind model.  I tried building the AS file, and it built.  But at runtime, I got the error "TypeError: Error #2023: Class MainAppClass$ must inherit from Sprite to link to the root."  When attempting to build the mxml file, I got the error C:\as\MainAppClass.mxml(8): Error: Could not resolve <component:MainAppClass> to a component implementation.
enterFrame="EnterFrame(event)">

What am I missing to build this?

Comment: @Nikhil, good choice. The code-behind model is pretty solid and helps with separating the display-related content from processing and data. As far as the error you're seeing, I expect it's based on an issue with trying to use the code-behind model w/the main MXML file.  I'll post an edit for something you might try.

Comment: I've gotten it working by making MainAppClass extend Application, and putting MainAppClass into a folder and inside a package with the same name as the folder.  I also had to rename the mxml class to something else, otherwise I got an ambiguous reference to MainAppClass error.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nikhil, outstanding - glad you figured it out :)